# TFS on VS2008 is not connecting to dev.azure.com

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, azure-devops

I have tried to install service pack1 as well as team foundation server with GDR compatibility on Visual Studio 2010 but still when I try to connect to dev.azure.com it throws error `unable to find TFS server` Can somebody please suggest how to resolve this issue.

Comment: Do you use VS 2008 or VS 2010? Could you share some screenshots of your steps?

Answer (score 0):

Double check you have installed the following two software updates for VS 2010:

- [Visual Studio 2010 Service Pack 1](https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=34677) (KB2736182)
- [TFS 2012 compatibility update for Visual Studio 2010](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/2662296/fix-an-update-for-visual-studio-2010-sp1-is-available-to-add-compatibi) (KB2662296)

And try to clear the cache folder on your client machine. The folder path is: `C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Team Foundation\x.0\Cache`. Make sure you type the correct server URL.

If the issue persists, you could add some screenshots of how you connected the server.